# Locomotive Liquid::SyntaxError at / Tag '{%' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\%\}/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, liquid, locomotivecms

I'm using HAML with Locomotive CMS's liquid templates. Recently, I received the following error:

```
Liquid::SyntaxError at /
Tag '{%' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\%\}/
```

I'm using a block tag to add classes to a `li` by overriding it from child template files. FYI, I'm using Liquid Inheritance which is included into Locomotive's Liquid fork.

```
%li.menu-list-item{:class => "{% block 'at_about_page' %}{% endblock %}"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I couldn't have both a `.class` in HAML format and also specify a `{:class => ""}` tag block.

Moving `menu-list-item` into the class attribute defined afterward works:

```
%li{:class => "menu-list-item {% block 'at_about_page' %}{% endblock %}"}
```